# Use local install of Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I already have phonegap 4.2 installed globally in my system, but for a project I need to run Cordova 3.6.. I installed cordova 3.6 **locally**. I'm on Win7x64 btw.
I can create a project from the node_module/.bin, but can't add a platform to it..

```
c:\test\node_modules\.bin>cordova create "test" "test" c:\test\app
Creating a new cordova project with name "test" and id "test" at location "c:\test\app"
c:\test\node_modules\.bin>cordova platform add android c:\test\app
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

How do i add a platform in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution so I might as well share it. I typed in the prompt at `c:\test\app>set PATH=%PATH%;c:\test\node_modules\.bin` then ran `c:\test\app>cordova platform add android`